# TensorFlow Probability inference error input type

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-probability

I train a model using tensorflow_probability and distributions.

To train it I format my data like this (2 heads model so 2 inputs set):

```
input_1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Xdata)
input_2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Xphysio)
output = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(yobs)
combined_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(((input_1, input_2), output))
input_dataset = combined_dataset.batch(30)
```

Trainning work well... but when I try to do inference like in this [exemple](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/main/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression.ipynb) at cell #15 they call the model like this:

```
yhats = model(combined_dataset)
```

I got the error

```
TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <ZipDataset element_spec=((TensorSpec(shape=(120, 9), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(24,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

I try:

```
yhats = model([input_1, input_2])
```

and got same error:

```
TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <TensorSliceDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(120, 9), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)>
```

using `yhats = model.predict([Xdata, Xphysio])` run well but seem to not return a valid format for tfd.Distribution:

```
assert isinstance(yhat, tfd.Distribution):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Windows programs\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is finaly a requirement to use tensorflow 2.13, I was 2.10.
I do the upgrade using pip in lieu of conda as usual and all work fine.